# Replacing individual oak strips in a pre-engineered wood flooring due to water damage

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, water-damage

My kitchen floor is Tarkett pre-engineered, pre-finished Long Strip oak (installed in 1986).  It was refinished professionally in 2017.  Recently it was damaged by water, resulting in multiple cupped strips in the middle of the kitchen floor.  I successfully flattened two of the 2-1/4" strips and plan to do that to all cupped strips after carefully removing them from the tongue-and-groove base. The oak strips are random in length (up to 24").  But, for those first two I find the fit to be extremely tight on the width and need to take some tiny amount off the long 1/8" thick edge in addition to removing the old glue from the bottom of each strip.  Previous responses on this site recommend Titebond III as the wood glue of choice.  The question I ask: what is the best tool for "sanding" the long edges?  What tool or sandpaper will be most effective?  I don't have special wood-working tools.  I would like to avoid the cost and hassle of having  the whole flooring refinished again, as it is installed on most of the main floor.

Comment: Have you thought about using a wood steamer and some weights and not removing the cupped flooring (just reshape it in place)?

Comment: Fresh Codemonger--no, I haven't, but it sounds more appropriate and easier than what I've suggested.  I'd like more information from you as to how one does that.  Thanks!

Comment: If it is only cupped, it will dry out in time all on its own. It needs to get back to it original moisture content. The multiple layers of flooring and subfloor trap the moisture and it will take a long time for it to get back where it was.

Comment: I have seen hardwood flooring go from cupped and horrible looking from a water leak back to the original state so it is possible it might just need to have some dry time....   maybe put a radiant dish heater pointed at the area to help dissipate the moisture.  That sounds like the easiest first attempt.

Comment: I've seen articles about cupped hardwood flooring returning to its original state, but this is not solid hardwood.  The water accident occurred 5/23/23.  The top layer (after one refinish is only about 1/8" thick and, where cupped, has become unglued from the base layer. That's why I was able to remove the two pieces I flattened so easily.  I ran a fan in the kitchen for 24 hours and already had the AC turned on.  I also placed heavy objects over many cupped spots and left them for a few days.  It may have helped flatten as the wood dried.  Still I have spots which are a hazard for tripping.